# How to make libs available in node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Assume a project `B` which depends on a node module `A`. `A` looks like this:

```
./node_modules/A
    ./src
        ./shared
            bar.js
            foo.js
    .... etc ....
```

In `B` I would like to use `bar.js` and `foo.js`
I can import these now as follows

```
import Bar from './node_modules/A/src/shared/bar';
import Bar from './node_modules/A/src/shared/bar';
```

Now the question is, is there a way such that I can do

```
import Bar from 'bar';   
import Foo from 'foo';
```

Is this possible ? Because I own module `A`, its no problem if this required changes to `A`!

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to tell node which paths to include when you do an import.

but this seems like a bad idea, off-hand.

if you need `foo` and `bar` available in both A and B, then they should be put into a new module on their own... module C.

then A and B can both import C

Comment: Ok. Does this mean that in the module's `package.json` a `"main" : "index.js"` is defined. And inside `index.js` I load and export both `bar.js` and `foo.js` ?

Comment: that's what i would do, yes.